# Strange effect in data-toggle

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, navbar

I have a bootstrap navbar in my site but when it is shown collapse, if click on a link the menu does not close, and I would like navigate to the page and the menu will also be closed.

I've added

```
data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
```

And do the trick, but the link have a strange effect when is not collapse (in a desktope mode)

I create a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/soyjuanmedina/rscdu7gv/3/

An add the code to the link 'Home' and you can see (you need to expand the result window to see the menu not collapsed) and see when click in it the words disappear to appear again

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the menu when on desktop doesn't dissapear it just changes its layout so it will still try and collapse it.

If you just need a fix for this and don't mind it being a bit messy, here's what I came up with.

Have two elements, one that will be visible on mobile and one that will be visible on desktop like this (pay attention to the **classes**)

**Mobile**:

```
<a class="nav-link d-block d-md-none" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent">
    Home
</a>
```

**Desktop**:

```
<a class="nav-link d-none d-md-block" href="#">
    Home
</a>
```

So **final result** would be:

```
<li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link d-none d-md-block" href="#">
        Home
    </a>
    <a class="nav-link d-block d-md-none" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent">
      Home
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks Halden, I will try, but is true it's a little messy... I works with angular, I don't know if is possible something with ng class.... but thanks a lot for your help